# Redirect issue in Iframe

Tags: iframe

Using SOAP call I am getting a URL and displaying in iframe.That URL contents one form, User need to fill all data and submit it. While I am invoking SOAP function, has given one return link also which one redirecting to my site.But problem is while returning that page is coming inside the iframe. My requirement is pretty clear that  it should redirect to given path not inside iframe.

I do appreciate for advance help.

Here is the code for Iframe

```
  <iframe style="width:955px;height:700px;margin: 0px auto;" src="<?php echo $response_data['Url']?>"  frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen id="js-signFrame">
</iframe>
```

Comment: I don't thing there is a possible way to handle this situation from client side, Unless the form tag's target attribute is set to `_parent` or `_top`

Answer (score 0):

If you have **control** over both the **host website** and the **iframe** content you can use [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/) to transfer messages between the iframe and the site (of course you can use HTML5 socket but easyXDM have a great fallback  mechanism which supports older browsers as well).
You can use the message logic to alter window.location of the parent window.

Here is a POC I made to show how to transfer data between different domains without getting caught  by browser's same-origin-policy, you can use it as reference.

link:
https://github.com/eitankw/cross-domain